# Android Studio don't recognise xml file in layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a xml file layout (`fragment_navigation.xml`) but android studio doesn't seem to recognise it as xml.

### *No xml icon*

[image: No xml icon]

### *No syntax highlight*

[image]

I create the same layout with different filename and it works for a time after close and open the project again.

My environment is:

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.2
```

Comment: how did you create the file?

Comment: @y.allam New -> Layout resource file. This loss the xml reference in the next open project

Comment: have you try to recreate again the file?

Comment: @Zuhrain Yes, I copied the code, deleted file and recreated again with the same code. But the issue appears again in next time when open the project.

Comment: This is a really long shot but have you tried to invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: @cmota Yes, I tried cache invalidation. Whatever, I post a solution below.. but I am a bit worried about the origin of this issue. Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity - if you make a diff between both files do you find anything different?

Comment: @cmota no differences according to git diff

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I saw an option **right-clicking on xml file "Mark as XML"**.

And it persist for next project opening.

[image]